# $(\omega+1)\cdot \omega=\omega ^2$ by definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I'm trying to show that:

$(\omega+1)\cdot \omega=\omega ^2$ by definition:

$(\omega+1)\cdot \omega= \text{sup}\{(\omega+1)\cdot n: n \in \omega\}$
I can see is that $(\omega+1) \cdot n = (\omega+1)+(\omega+1)+...+(\omega+1)= \omega+\omega+...+\omega+1$

how do i prove that sup is $\omega^2$?

Comment: what is $\omega$?

Comment: Ordinal number ?

Comment: @gt6989b: $\omega$ is the smallest infinite ordinal number, corresponding to the order type of the ordinary $<$ on $\mathbb N$. (In most developments of set theory it is represeted by the same set as $\mathbb N$).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\omega\cdot n<(\omega+1)\cdot n<\omega\cdot (n+1)$$